# How should we respond to an edit that removes the old 'Possible Duplicate' markdown?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, old-questions

I just made an edit to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89194/is-this-xbox-360-controller-fake-how-can-i-tell), and then noticed that it was marked as a duplicate . I couldn't however, see the duplicate notification at the top of the question.

Diving in to the [revision history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/89194/revisions), I can see that the OP deliberately removed the markdown of the duplicate question* (which pointed to: [How can I identify a counterfeit Xbox 360 controller?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31760/how-can-i-identify-a-counterfeit-xbox-360-controller))

Should I add this back in? or should we reopen and reclose the question so that the **new** duplicate markdown (the uneditable one) kicks in?

---

*For those that don't know, the 'Duplicate' message at the top used to be part of the question body, and still is on a lot of old questions marked as duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either roll it back, or just flag it and a mod can reopen/recluse to force the new header.

I've already done the latter in this case.